# como agregarle otra clausula al WHERE en esta consulta

Tags: python, sqlite3

tengo este Script en sqlite que busca en la columna NOMBRE, funciona perfectamente pero quisera poder agregarle otro WHERE para que tenga pendiente la FECHA, como podria agregarlo?

```
def buscador_ventana_facturacion(self):#buscar en reporte_cuadre
         if self.buscador_facturacion.get() != "":
            self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.delete(*self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.get_children())#limpia la tabla
            query= ("SELECT nro, id_cliente, nombre, credito_fiscal, forma_pago, total, fecha FROM reporte_cuadre WHERE nombre LIKE ?", ('%' + str(self.buscador_facturacion.get()) + '%',))
            cursor =self.run_query(*query)
            fetch = cursor.fetchall()
            for data in fetch:
                self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.insert('', 'end', values=(data))
            cursor.close()
         else: self.consulta_facturas()#
```

Este es el WHERE que deceo agregar ya que tiene en cuenta la fecha, la idea es que al buscar por texto tenga en cuenta la fecha tambien

```
WHERE fecha >= '{self.calendario_inicio_factura.get_date()}' and fecha <= '{self.calendario_final_factura.get_date()}'
```

Comment: Para usar múltiples `where` se usa `AND` quedando más o menos de está manera `SELECT nro .... FROM reporte_cuadre where nombre like .... AND fecha => self.calendario_inicio_factura.get_date() AND <= self.calendario_final_factura.get_date()`, en este caso para manejar rango de fechas es mejor que uses `BETWEEN `

Comment: Esperemos que las fechas estén guardadas en formato YYYY-MM-DD. Si no, tendrás que hacer conversiones, las búsquedas demorarán más y serán menos eficientes.

Comment: Saludos @Daniel ya probe agregando el AND luego de LIKE ? pero la sintaxis no es correcta y falla.

Comment: y como lo probaste? como quedo el query? porque lo que tenes que hacer es justamente lo que te dijeron...

Comment: saludos @gbianchi asi lo coloque pero da el error de que el WHERE esta mal colocado: query= (f"SELECT nro, id_cliente, nombre, credito_fiscal, forma_pago, total, fecha FROM reporte_cuadre WHERE nombre LIKE ? AND WHERE fecha >= '{self.calendario_inicio_factura.get_date()}' and fecha <= '{self.calendario_final_factura.get_date()}' ", ('%' + str(self.buscador_facturacion.get()) + '%',))

Comment: El `where` ya no usa dos veces, para eso usas el `AND` , `f"SELECT nro, id_cliente, nombre, credito_fiscal, forma_pago, total, fecha FROM reporte_cuadre WHERE nombre LIKE ? AND  fecha >= '{self.calendario_inicio_factura.get_date()}' and fecha <= '{self.calendario_final_factura.get_date()}' ", ('%' + str(self.buscador_facturacion.get()) + '%',)`

Comment: ooh no sabia q se omitia el WHERE, ponlo como respuesta para aceptarla

Comment: no se omite el where.... es la forma en que se escriben multiples clausulas.. tampoco pondrias dos veces el from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar múltiples where se usa **`AND`** quedando más o menos de está manera `SELECT nro .... FROM reporte_cuadre where nombre like .... AND fecha => self.calendario_inicio_factura.get_date() AND <= self.calendario_final_factura.get_date()`, en este caso para manejar rango de fechas es mejor que uses **`BETWEEN`**.

si buscas solo copiar y pegar, tu query quedaría de esta manera

```
SELECT nro, id_cliente, nombre, credito_fiscal, forma_pago, total, fecha FROM reporte_cuadre WHERE nombre LIKE ? AND  fecha >= '{self.calendario_inicio_factura.get_date()}' and fecha <= '{self.calendario_final_factura.get_date()}' ", ('%' + str(self.buscador_facturacion.get()) + '%',).
```

tambien puedes usar `BETWEEN` como te habia comentado

```
SELECT nro, id_cliente, nombre, credito_fiscal, forma_pago, total, fecha FROM reporte_cuadre WHERE nombre LIKE ? AND  fecha BETWEEN'{self.calendario_inicio_factura.get_date()}' and '{self.calendario_final_factura.get_date()}' ", ('%' + str(self.buscador_facturacion.get()) + '%',).
```

Comment: eh.. tambien se puede usar OR... dependiendo que nesecites.. y tambien se usan parentesis para invertir el orden de precedencia...

Comment: pero `OR` no cumple en este caso, es mejor usa `AND`, `OR` significa `o`, que en este caso, es validar la primera fecha en caso de que no tengas datos, consultara la segunda, es decir , `fecha >= '{self.calendario_inicio_factura.get_date()}' ` no trae datos, tendra que devolver los registros del segundo , `self.calendario_final_factura.get_date()`, es decir no cumple el rango que el especifica, mi recomendación es mejor usar `BETWEEN`

Comment: saludos @Daniel que aporta el BETWEEN? porque sin este funciona perfectamente.

Comment: si.. perfecto, lo decia por la frase "Para usar múltiples where se usa AND", que dado que OP no tenia ni idea que existia, suena a que es lo unico que existe ;)

Comment: @wally google es tu amigo ;)

Comment: igual, between es solo una mejora visual, internamente se traduce a clausula 1 and clausula 2, exactamente como las escribiste...

Comment: @wally como comenta @gbianchi, es lo mismo que `fecha >= 'self.ca..' and fecha <= '{self.calendario_final_factura..'`,  que hacer esto `fecha between 'self.ca..' and '{self.calendario_final_factura'`